# Form Submission Issue (page load error first time)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm having issues when using a form to insert data into a local database. For whatever reason the first time the submit button is clicked a "Error Loading Page" message pops up and the form page refreshes, but if I reenter information into the form and click the button again the data is entered into the database and the page moves on to the correct place at #MoneyOrdersMain. I am confused as to what could be causing this. Any help would be appreciated. Particularly what would be causing the form to not submit the first time?

The Form:

```
<form method="post" id="moneyorder_form" name="moneyorder_form" onsubmit="MOsubmit()">
            <!-- onsubmit="closeSelf()"> -->
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <p style="text-align: center; display: inline"><b>Number</b></p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="number" required="required" step="1" id="moCNumber" name="moCNumber">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <p style="text-align: center; display: inline"><b>Amount</b></p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="number" required="required" min=".01" step=".01" id="moCAmount" name="moCAmount">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="Add" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

MOsubmit() function:

```
function MOsubmit() {
insertMoC($('#moCNumber').val(), $('#moCAmount').val(), "MoneyOrder");
$.mobile.changePage('#MoneyOrdersMain');
location.reload(true);
}

function insertMoC(moCNumber, moCAmount, moCType) {
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MoneyOrderChecks (moCNumber, moCAmount, moCType) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [moCNumber, moCAmount, moCType]);
});
}
```

Comment: what is the functionality of MOsubmit?

Comment: I use it as the function for the form submission on which the information from the form is inserted into the database and redirects the user to a new page so that they can see the information displayed in the database.

Comment: What is `insertMoC()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've figured out part of what the issue was in case anyone else runs into this same type of problem. The page #MoneyOrdersMain that I was attempting to call as part of my form submission function is the parent of the page that held form.   This seemed to be causing a problem when the form was submitted for the first time. Since the MOsubmit function included a refresh of the form page #MoneyOrdersMain was no longer the "parent" and could accept the form data. Everything works fine now that I have redirect the user to a page other than #MoneyOrdersMain in the form submission function. However, #MoneyOrdersMain is where I'd ultimately like the user to end up after the form submits, so that is my next challenge.